# Remove subtotal from confirmation mail woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove total and subtotal from woocommerce new order mail. This code works for total but subtotal is still displayed.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'reordering_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function reordering_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $shipping = $total_rows['line_subtotal'];
    $order_total = $total_rows['order_total'];

    unset($total_rows['line_subtotal']);
    unset($total_rows['order_total']);


    return $total_rows;
}
```

I tried `['line_subtotal']`, `['order_subtotal']`, `['subtotal']` do you know its name?

Thank you a lot

Comment: you can always do `var_dump($total_rows);` to check the variable

Comment: Yes it's true thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code in functions.php file

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'reordering_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function reordering_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $shipping = $total_rows['cart_subtotal'];
    $order_total = $total_rows['order_total'];

    unset($total_rows['cart_subtotal']);
    unset($total_rows['order_total']);


    return $total_rows;
}
```